# Scenario: development and production code management with Git

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

So my company has two web servers: prod and development. These are remote servers. Right now we don't have any good workflow in place to manage the code. Whenever we need to make any changes to the website, we do it directly on the production code. I want to introduce git and make all this a bit more professional.

One idea I have in my mind is - I set up a GitHub repo and make two different branches - main and dev branch. Do all the changes in dev branch and then merge it into prod when we want to deploy the new changes. The problem with this process is that suppose I'm working on some CSS to change the appearance of a webpage, now ideally I would want to see changes in real time as I make any edits (say padding). But with the introduction of git, I will have to commit and push even the smallest changes to see how they look on the website.

This workflow will introduce so many unnecessary commits and pushes, and will also make the whole process time consuming.

What is the industry (ideal) way of doing this? What should be the workflow?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's not the title of a thesis. :)

Comment: Your question implies that code is deployed via Git (it often isn't--it's just tracked with Git), and that you'd do CSS development _on the server_, instead of locally. I'm befuddled by both of those. I need some clarity around your assumed workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on enterprise level web development for a number or years, rule number 1 is NEVER make changes to production code. This is going to sound negative but I truly do not mean it that way - you have a workflow problem and git cannot fix this.

Create yourself a real development environment either on your local development machine, a staging server, etc. Make your changes and validate the change in your development environment. Only then does that change go to the production server.

Typical Scenario:
Developer makes change and tests it locally.
Developer commits the change to the git repo.
A build is executed using the latest commits from the git repo.
The build is delivered to the staging/test environment to validate.
If the staging/test environment test are successful - the build is delivered to the production environment.

All of these steps can be automated using some basic scripts. After getting your workflow initiated, follow up and start implementing a more refined CI/CD structure.

Within my current development aspects, I do these same basic "make a change, check it locally", but when I commit the code change, the build server will detect the change and run the build automatically, execute all the unit test, and if all unit tests are passing, deploy the build to the staging server. This all happens while I am getting a fresh cup of coffee.

Comment: That's exactly I wanted to know, sorry for bad representation of my question. So is it very common in enterprise level that most of the time changes are tested on LOCAL computer? does that also means each developer who is contributing to the code will need to install a full copy of server on their local computer?

Comment: @govidon: you don't necessarily need a full copy of the entire setup. It's often extremely useful to have *enough* of the setup to run common things. For testing purposes, though, you do need a full copy of the entire setup *somewhere*, where the projected next-to-be-deployed system gets installed and tested thoroughly. Depending on scope, $, and numerous other constraints, that could be a second system that's used if the primary system goes down (which then stops all development until the primary system is restored), or a third system separate from the primary's backup, or...

Comment: These aren't really *stack overflow* questions and such though, where we're concerned with niggling details and [technical correctness](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/48a9bw/why_is_technically_correct_the_best_kind_of/) rather than anything practical. 